# Why {} cannot be removed? And why char type variable cannot be transferred?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#ifndef ClassTemplate_HH
#define ClassTemplate_HH

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T1,typename T2>
class myClass{
private:
     T1 I;
     T2 J;
public:
     myClass(T1 a, T2 b);//Constructor
     void show();
};

//这是构造函数
//注意这些格式
template <typename T1,typename T2>
myClass<T1,T2>::myClass(T1 a,T2 b):I(a),J(b){}

//这是void show();
template <typename T1,typename T2>
void myClass<T1,T2>::show()
{
     cout<<"I="<<I<<", J="<<J<<endl;
}

#endif
```

In the above header file, the `{}` cannot be removed, why? And what's purpose of it?

```
myClass<T1,T2>::myClass(T1 a,T2 b):I(a),J(b){}
```

Below is the source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassTemplate.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
     myClass<int,int> class1(3,5);
     class1.show();

     myClass<int,char> class2(3,"a");
     class2.show();

     myClass<double,int> class3(2.9,10);
     class3.show();
}
```

And the error compile result is as below:

```
$ g++ ClassTemplate_Test.cpp 
ClassTemplate_Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ClassTemplate_Test.cpp:12:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
ClassTemplate.h:20:1: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘myClass<T1, T2>::myClass(T1, T2) [with T1 = int, T2 = char]’ [-fpermissive]
```

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: It's (the body of) the definition of the constructor. It's empty, but even an empty definition is a definition. It's necessary to define the constructor.

Comment: Try passing 'a' instead of "a". 'a' is a char, "a" is a const char *.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myClass<T1,T2>::myClass(T1 a,T2 b):I(a),J(b){}
```

Here `{}` is the constructor's entire function body. It is essentially an empty constructor, since all the work is done in the [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

It can be rewritten to see better that the braces are just your run of the mill function body.

```
myClass<T1,T2>::myClass(T1 a,T2 b)
   :I(a),J(b)
{

}
```

As to your **compile error**, a simple fix from "" to '' would take care of it,

Change

```
myClass<int,char> class2(3,"a");
```

to

```
myClass<int,char> class2(3,'a');
```

This is because `"a"` is treated as a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) whose type is `const char *`. `'a'`, on the other hand, is treated as a `char` as you and your constructor would expect.

Comment: +1. It is like writing `void f(){}` which is a function with empty body.

Answer (score 3):

```
myClass<T1,T2>::myClass(T1 a,T2 b):I(a),J(b){}
```

This defines a function. Functions have a body. The body of a function is defined as the stuff between curly-braces (ie: {}). So even if the function is empty, you must define it with a pair of braces.